# remove bootstrap 5 validation right icon on select tag

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@latest/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="validationCustom04" class="form-label">State</label>
    <select class="form-select" id="validationCustom04" required>
      <option selected disabled value="">Choose</option>
      <option>option1</option>
    </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please select a valid state.
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can we remove that right icon image on select tag (bootstrap 5.2)

Comment: The [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/?#custom-styles) says to remove the  "novalidate" attribute from the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its specifically for the select tag

add this CSS

```
.form-select.is-valid:not([multiple]):not([size]), .form-select.is-valid:not([multiple])[size="1"], .was-validated .form-select:valid:not([multiple]):not([size]), .was-validated .form-select:valid:not([multiple])[size="1"] {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23343a40' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='m2 5 6 6 6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
```